# Pass function with argument from within formatted print statement, with arguments from {}

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi r/python programmers.

I'm trying to input a function inside formatted print statatement in python 3.  The function has arguments which I want to  get from the formatted print {}. But upon doing so, it's not passed. How to achieve this?

Code #1 > Error Handler Function

```
# >> function :: error pop# msg = error message , shutdown = True or Falsedef pop_error(msg, shutdown):if shutdown == True:print(f"[{c_red}{msg}{c_white}] Exiting..")exit()elif shutdown == False:print(f"[{c_red}{msg}{c_white}]")
```

Code #2 > Calling Error Handler

```
# global variablesglobal engine_argglobal async_arg# check selected engineif engine_arg == 'ddg':print("Starting DDG")elif engine_arg == 'pbin':print("Starting Pastebin")else:#pop_error("Invlaid Engine {?engine_arg?}", True)print(f"{pop_error('Invalid Engine {engine_arg}', True)}")exit()
```

Edit: The main issue is that I'm unable to add local variable inside the double quotes for the first argument of function. That's why I used formatted string so that I can use "{variable}", but this doesn't seem possible inside  the quotes of the function despite using print(f)..

Solved: `print(f"{pop_error(f'Invalid Engine {engine_arg}', True)}"`

Image References: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfEF0.jpg

Comment: Instead of using ```f-string```, just use ```print(pop_error(arg1, arg2))```

Comment: I tried, but I want to include the local variable as well.. print(pop_error("Invalid Engine:? ", True)) in place of "?", that's why I wanted to use formatted string so that I could use {variable} inside the double quotes..

Comment: The outer f-string seems pointless, try ```print(pop_error(f'Invalid Engine {engine_arg}', True))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> itworks = 'wow it worked'
>>> f'''{f'{itworks}'}'''
>>> 'wow it worked'

# in you case


print(f"{pop_error(f'Invalid Engine {engine_arg}', True)}"
```

Comment: THANKS THIS WORKS! YOU'RE GENIUS. HOW COME I NEVER THINK ABOUT THIS!! WE CAN PUT ENTIRE STATEMENTS INSIDE { } .. :D